# Refering to a directory in a Flask app doesn't work unless the path is absolute

Tags: python, flask, nltk

I downloaded nltk data into the data directory in my Flask app. The views reside in a blueprint in another directory on the same level as the data directory.  In the view I'm trying to set the path to the data, but it doesn't work.

```
nltk.data.path.append('../nltk_data/')
```

This doesn't work. If I use the whole path, it does work.

```
nltk.data.path.append('/home/username/myapp/app/nltk_data/')
```

Why does the first form not work?  How can I refer to the location of the data correctly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Python (and most languages), where the code resides in a package is different than what the working directory is when running a program.  All relative paths are relative to the current working directory, not the code file it's written in.  So you would use the relative path `nltk_data/` even from a blueprint, or you would use the absolute path and leave no ambiguity.

The `root_path` attribute on an app (or blueprint) refers to the package directory for the app (or blueprint).  Join your relative path to that to get the absolute path.

```
resource_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'enltk_data')
```

---

There's probably no reason to be appending this folder every time you call a view.  I'm not familiar with nltk specifically, but there's probably a way to structure this so you set up the data path once when you create your app.

---

```
project    /    app    /    blueprint
                       /    data

                            ^ join with root_path to get here
                ^ app.root_path always points here, no matter where cwd is
^ current working directory
```